# crontab runs only 2nd line

Tags: cron

I have /etc/cron.d/remote-server-backup as follows:

```
***starts***
MAILTO="log@automatem.co.nz"
23 1,7,13,19 * * * root /usr/local/bin/backup-server nzs1.automatem.co
43 2,8,14,20 * * * root /usr/local/bin/backup-server nzs2.automatem.co

***ends***
```

The script is custom written and performs an incremental backup with rsync.

I'm finding that nzs2.automatem.co script runs every 6 hours, the nzs1.automatem.co script runs never. I don't get any emails on log@automatem.co.nz. When I run from command line nzs1.automatem.co, it performs the backup correctly.

My Environment is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

How can I get the first line to run automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: *From the comments, the problem was caused by the `""` around the MAILTO: email address.*

There is nothing obviously wrong with the crontab you show providing that the `***starts***` and `***ends***` aren't really in it.

It's not normal to see `""` around the email address so you could try removing them.

Next check your logs for any relevant information. You don't say which OS or distro you're using but /var/log/cron (RHEL based), /var/log/syslog (Debian based) but they could be elsewhere.

```
grep -r CRON /var/log/*
```

If the logs don't indicate a problem and the `/usr/local/bin/backup-server` script is seen to be run they your problem lies within it so you'll have to break out your script debugging skills.

Comment: It seems the " around the email broke it. Other comments: 1) Thanks for the grep reminder, I had overlooked the CRON calls among all the other ones. 2) I had no MTA installed